# SQL queries for time series scenarios

Tags: sql, oracle

Data sets:

[image]

I've got a functional use case for which data structure is shown in the attachment.

Tab 1 is a source table & tab 2 is the destination table. Based on the state of sleep i need to fill in alive state matching with start seq & end seq so that it avoids any overlapping. I tried with pl/sql procedure & its working. However when the dataset tends to be large , lets say 10 million tab 2 generations taking huge amount of time.

Any other suggestions how to implement in an Oracle database? Tried with Oracle-model clause but in vain

Comment: Please do not post screen shots and provide data examples see here:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Also update your question with the SQL you’ve managed to write so far. I assume 19 on the first row of your result is a typo?

Comment: Okay, point noted

Comment: Hi Nick - Truly speaking i couldn't write the Sql but i managed to complete it by pl/sql , row by row processing. Answering to your questions yes it should have been 9

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT pk,
       state,
       start_seq
         + CASE WHEN state = 'Alive' AND prev_sleep > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         AS start_seq,
       end_seq
         - CASE WHEN state = 'Alive' AND next_sleep > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         AS end_seq
FROM   (
  SELECT seq,
         SUM(CASE state WHEN 'Alive' THEN type ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY seq) AS alive,
         SUM(CASE state WHEN 'Sleep' THEN type ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY seq) AS sleep,
         state
  FROM   table_name
         UNPIVOT(seq FOR type IN (start_seq AS 1, end_seq AS -1))
)
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER BY seq
  MEASURES
    MATCH_NUMBER() AS pk,
    CLASSIFIER()   AS state,
    FIRST(seq)     AS start_seq,
    NEXT(seq)      AS end_seq,
    PREV(sleep)    AS prev_sleep,
    NEXT(sleep)    AS next_sleep
  PATTERN ( "Alive"+ | "Sleep"+ )
  DEFINE
    "Sleep" AS sleep > 0,
    "Alive" AS sleep = 0 AND alive > 0
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (pk, state, start_seq, end_seq) AS
SELECT 1, 'Alive',  1, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Sleep', 10,  25 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Sleep', 50,  60 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Sleep', 70,  81 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| PK | STATE | START_SEQ | END_SEQ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alive | 1 | 9 |
| 2 | Sleep | 10 | 25 |
| 3 | Alive | 26 | 49 |
| 4 | Sleep | 50 | 60 |
| 5 | Alive | 61 | 69 |
| 6 | Sleep | 70 | 81 |
| 7 | Alive | 82 | 100 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DC0pAeTP)

Comment: Wow ! It's the use case of of match_recognize ? Great. I'm testing it too. And heartfelt thanks to provide it with the new feature of Oracle12c & I'll use this sql as a guide to learn match_recognize .

Answer (score 2):

One of the optins could be using union and case expressions with LAG() analytic function:

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
  tab_1 (PK, STATE, START_SEQ, END_SEQ) AS
    ( Select 1, 'Alive',  1, 100 From Dual Union All
      Select 2, 'Sleep', 10,  25 From Dual Union All
      Select 3, 'Sleep', 50,  60 From Dual Union All
      Select 4, 'Sleep', 70,  81 From Dual 
    ),
```

```sql
--  CTE used just in last unioned query to create last row of the resultset
  alive_span AS
    ( Select Min(START_SEQ) "MIN_ALIVE", Max(END_SEQ) "MAX_ALIVE"
      From tab_1
      Where STATE = 'Alive'
    )
```

```sql
--      M a i n    S Q L :
SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() Over(Order By START_SEQ, STATE) "PK", x.STATE, x.START_SEQ, x.END_SEQ
       -- first query gets all sleep periods rows
FROM  (   Select      STATE, START_SEQ, END_SEQ From tab_1 Where STATE = 'Sleep'
      UNION ALL
       -- second query generates alive periods rows
          Select      'Alive' "STAT", 
                      Case When LAG(STATE) Over(Order By START_SEQ) = 'Alive' And START_SEQ - LAG(START_SEQ) Over(Order By START_SEQ) > 1
                           Then  LAG(START_SEQ) Over(Order By START_SEQ) 
                           When LAG(STATE) Over(Order By START_SEQ) = 'Sleep' And START_SEQ - LAG(START_SEQ) Over(Order By START_SEQ) > 1
                           Then  LAG(END_SEQ) Over(Order By START_SEQ) + 1
                      End "START_SEQ",
                      Case When LAG(STATE) Over(Order By START_SEQ) = 'Alive' And START_SEQ - LAG(START_SEQ) Over(Order By START_SEQ) > 1
                           Then  START_SEQ - 1 
                           When LAG(STATE) Over(Order By START_SEQ) = 'Sleep' And START_SEQ - LAG(START_SEQ) Over(Order By START_SEQ) > 1
                           Then  START_SEQ - 1
                      End "END_SEQ"
          From        tab_1 
      UNION ALL
        -- third query generates last row if last END_SEQ of sleep rows is less then max alive span
          Select      'Alive' "STATE", Max(t.END_SEQ) + 1 "START_SEQ", Max(a.MAX_ALIVE) "END_SEQ"
          From        tab_1 t
          Inner Join  alive_span a ON( 1 = 1 )
          Where       t.STATE = 'Sleep' 
          Having      Max(t.END_SEQ) < Max(a.MAX_ALIVE)    
      ) x
WHERE    x.START_SEQ Is Not Null
ORDER BY x.START_SEQ, x.STATE
```

```sql
/*     R e s u l t :
        PK STATE  START_SEQ    END_SEQ
---------- ----- ---------- ----------
         1 Alive          1          9
         2 Sleep         10         25
         3 Alive         26         49
         4 Sleep         50         60
         5 Alive         61         69
         6 Sleep         70         81
         7 Alive         82        100    */
```

Comment: This one is pretty sophisticated. Thanks I'm testing it.